# Checking multiple columns have any of multiple values in a Table value parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am trying to create a query to help get a list of accounts from an existing database. I will have two lists of integers passed in through two Table Value Parameters(TVP) from C#. I then need to see if multiple columns have any of the values in the corresponding TVP tables. The TVP lists of integers are provided by different clients and may differ between clients. That is why they are TVP's to allow the values to be passed in as parameters.

The data structure cannot be changed, it is created based on data from another system. Comments about changing the data structure won't be helpful. To help I will talk about an example table that would help show what I need.

Looking at a table like the following:

```
Table Accounts
  varchar(200) AccountId
  int StatusId1
  int StatusId2
  int StatusId3
  int StatusId4
  int Identifier1
  int Identifier2
  int Identifier3
  int Identifier4
  int Identifier5
```

I know that I can do a sql statement like:

`Select AccountId from Accounts where StatusId1 In (1,2,3)`

I was able to learn that I can reverse the In command as well:

`Select AccountId from Accounts where 1 In (StatusId1, StatusId2, StatusId3, StatusId4)`

This only lets me check one value against each column. The problem is I need to mix the two while using the TVP for the list of integers.

The closest I have been able to create is the following:

```
--Load the TVP lists 
SELECT * INTO #StatusCodes FROM @StatusId
SELECT * INTO #IdentityCodes FROM @IdentifierId

--Find the Accounts that have the chosen Ids
SELECT AccountId
FROM Accounts
WHERE StatusId1 IN( SELECT Id FROM #StatusCodes)
OR StatusId2 IN( SELECT Id FROM #StatusCodes)
OR StatusId3 IN( SELECT Id FROM #StatusCodes)
OR StatusId4 IN( SELECT Id FROM #StatusCodes)
OR Identifier1 IN (SELECT Id FROM #IdentityCodes)
OR Identifier2 IN (SELECT Id FROM #IdentityCodes)
OR Identifier3 IN (SELECT Id FROM #IdentityCodes)
OR Identifier4 IN (SELECT Id FROM #IdentityCodes)
OR Identifier5 IN (SELECT Id FROM #IdentityCodes)
```

This query worked in my prototype and I got back the list of accounts that had at least one of these ids.  I see a lot of select statements and it doesn't look very good. I am not sure how well it performs either. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

This is for a system that creates a report based on conditions our clients make. Each client runs from a couple to 100 reports each night. That means this is run possibly hundreds of times each night. While it isn't a system running thousands of times per hour, it does process a lot of data. Some of the databases it will search will be big with lots of accounts to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses `exists`:

```
select a.acountId
from accounts a
where 
    exists (
        select 1 
        from #StatusCodes s 
        where s.id in (a.StatusId1, a.StatusId2, a.StatusId3, a.StatusId4)
    )
    or exists (
        select 1 
        from #IdentityCodes i 
        where i.id in (a.Identifier1, a.Identifier2, a.Identifier3, a.Identifier4)
    )
```

Comment: I was able to recreate this in my test project. The query worked great. It looks better than the query I created. I was also able to run some timing in my test app with a test database. This query ran quicker each time. Thanks.